# Control parallelism with BrightFutures, a "future" implementation in Swift

Tags: swift, parallel-processing, multicore, concurrent.futures

BrightFutures is a nice implementation of "future" in the Swift language.
https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures

I like to control the parallelism of multicore CPU with it.  Does someone know a way to control the # of CPU cores/physical threads to be used?

Answer (score 1):

All closures passed to BrightFutures are executed according to BF's [default threading model](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures#default-threading-model). It seems like you want to diverge from the default model. This is possible by passing a [custom execution context](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures#custom-execution-contexts).

An execution context that limits the number of parallel tasks it executes, could be created with the following function:

```
func executionContextWithControlledParallelism(p: Int) -> ExecutionContext {
        let s = Semaphore(value: p)
        let q = Queue.global.context
        return { task in
            s.wait()
            q {
                task()
                s.signal()
            }
        }
    }
```

I tested this briefly using the following code:

```
let context = executionContextWithControlledParallelism(5)

for _ in 0..<100 {
    future(context:context) { () -> Int in
        return fibonacci(Int(arc4random_uniform(15)))
    }
}
```

You'll have to pass `context` to every `map`, `flatMap`, etc. that you want to limit the parallelism of. I'll admit that seems cumbersome. A better way (that is currently **not** supported by BrightFutures) would be to set the default threading model, like this:

```
let context = executionContextWithControlledParalelism(5)

// this is not supported right now:
BrightFutures.setDefaultThreadingModel(model: {
    return context
})
```

If you like this, please consider filing an issue to request this or (even better) create a pull request.

Comment: BrightFutures is an excellent tool. However, IMHO it might be dangerous to define an API where we can define an _implicit_  default context. It's too easy to just forget about what the actual execution context is - which may introduce subtle bugs likes race conditions, deadlocks etc.. I would prefer to be very explicit when it comes to select an execution context.

Comment: By the way, did you consider to utilise _curried functions_ (a _free_ function) which take a future and a context as params and where we can define partly defined functions bearing the future and an associated execution context?

Comment: Thomas, your solution might not work well: since the custom execution context will _block_, it also will block it's call-site. When looking at the implementation of BF there are a couple places where this might lead to issues (dead-locks). Luckily, it's entirely possible to implement such a constrained queue with an asynchronous pattern. All you have to ensure is, that the scheduling of the closure (`task`) occurs _asynchronously_. Sure, the implementation of such a queue becomes more elaborate.

Comment: Thanks Thomvis!  I've confirmed that it works with my 4 core MacBookPro.  I have 12-core MacPro in my lab and I will try.

Comment: Our lab has also 80-core HP Linux machine.  I like to use Swift and BrightFutures in the machine, when Apple release the Linux version of Swift in the coming fall hopefully.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks for your feedback! I think BF needs a default model, because you don't want to specify the explicit context for every callback. That being said, the default one is tailored to (iOS) app development. You're right about the call-site blocking, that's not good. The .sync should either be moved into the closure (but then you have waiting threads) or requires asynchronous scheduling. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @kzhk good to hear, but please take CouchDeveloper's concerns into account.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper re curried functions. I'm not sure if I see the benefits or if I'm misunderstanding. If you want to discuss this further, it might be better to file an issue on GitHub?